# Application Strangler Pattern Experiences & Thoughts

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

Just recently I came over an idea called the **Application Strangler Pattern**. As I understand it it is a solution to the problem with large legacy systems. The idea is to create a new application *around* the old application. The cost and risk of this will be much less than a complete rewrite of the system. Slowly, over time, the new application will do more and more of the work and eventually strangle the old legacy application. In the mean time developers get to work in a clean, new system with higher efficiency and hopefully producing much better code.

Where I work now we have come to the point were new functionality, even seemingly trivial things, takes a long time to develop, with a high risk of breaking something. We sit on about a million lines of code, with unit test coverage of perhaps 1-2%. The system is a SOA system using web services (neither is really necessary) and is more procedural in style than object oriented. The system is both web & win, all written in .net programming languages.

**Finally the question:**
In considering this new idea/pattern, I want to know if anyone has had any experience with using this pattern they would like to share. For example, what would be a good way of implementing it (hooking up to events from the old application, for example)? Also, if anyone has any thoughts on the subject, why it would be a good or bad idea, that would be appreciated as well.

**References:**

- [Martin Fowler blog post](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/StranglerApplication.html)
- [Hanselminutes with Michael Feathers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast165WorkingEffectivelyWithLegacyCodeWithMichaelFeathers.aspx)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The biggest problem to overcome is lack of will to actually finish the strangling (usually political will from non-technical stakeholders, manifested as lack of budget).  If you don't completely kill off the old system, you'll end up in a worse mess because your system now has two ways of doing everything with an awkward interface between the two.  Later, another wave of developers will probably decide to strangle what's there, writing yet another strangler application, and again a lack of will might leave the system in an even worse state, with three ways of doing things.

If the project is large, run from multiple regions, then you HAVE to get global consensus on what the final state should look like and how everyone is going to cooperate to get there. While the old app is being strangled, it's vital for remote teams to communicate every day, cooperate on the work if possible by doing remote pair programming, and resolve any misunderstandings or disagreements as soon as they arise. Otherwise there's the danger that each regional team will decide to write their own strangler application and they will meet somewhere in the middle and battle it out, leaving the system even worse.

Whatever you do, do not do the refactoring/strangling in a different branch from the main stream of development.  The merge difficulties will become insurmountable.

I've seen critical systems that have suffered both of these fates, and ended up with about four or five "strategic architectural directions" and "future state architectures".  One large multi-site project ended up with eight different new persistence mechanisms in its new architecture.  Another ended up with two different database schemas, one for the old way of doing things and another for the new way, neither schema was ever removed from the system and there were also multiple class hierarchies that mapped to one or even both of these schemas.

Finally, if you're introducing technologies that are new to the team or to support/maintenance staff (e.g. adding reliable async messaging to what is currently a synchronous three-tier client/server architecture) then you have to ensure that there are experienced technical leads on the project who know how to build systems with that technology, and support those systems.  And those tech leads have to stick with the project for some time after the old app has been fully strangled.  Otherwise, the architecture will degrade as inexperienced developers modify it in ways they know but not in ways that fit with the new architecture.

Comment: We decided to not go for this pattern for now anyway. I've set this answer as the correct one even though it is hard to say that the other answers are less correct, but at least this one was the most thorough.

Answer (score 9):

The big risk of this pattern is that you end up bodging both the old code AND the new code to get the behaviour you need, especially if the old code was never designed to be strangled (i.e. does not present clean consistent interfaces).

My experience with this has been that debugging becomes harder over time as it's unclear whether problematic functionality has arisen in the new code or the old code (or a shared problem between the two).

I know Martin Fowler talks about writing code that is designed to be strangled, but in my opinion that is simply another way of saying that modular design is good, mmmkay; it's non-controversial and fairly obvious.

Answer (score 5):

The basic premise behind the strangler is really great: instead of trying to do a "big bang" style all at once replacement of a legacy system, you instead build a strangler application by making vertical slices down the layers, replacing each existing feature one by one until the original system can be decommissioned. It works well, in theory and in practice - probably one of the best things about it is that it greatly reduces technology risk and helps a team focus on replacing the most important features. If the new system doesn't work, people can simply use the old system.

**What could go wrong?**

- Organizations may find that it can become difficult to keep long term
  infrastructure refresh projects funded in the wake of new projects
  that promise new features, competitive advantage, revenue potential,
  or increase marketshare – especially for organizations that are
  focused on a product or service. This is one of those immediately
  visible problems, and while its an easy scapegoat, it’s typically not
  the only threat.
- When the system
  being replaced is overly connected with the system replacing it, this
  can cause the technical difficulty to increase dramatically – it
  might be OK to have them share one specific integration point, but
  more than that is trouble. When the team becomes distracted by the
  technology challenges they’ve created for themselves, they’re not
  longer working effectively and the project timelines spiral out of
  control.
- Technology teams that are horizontally organized may have an
  especially hard time with the StranglerApplication Pattern, as the
  vertical slices required to finish the work require integration with
  several departments or teams to complete, and each group has its own
  release cycles, goals, and organizational pressures.
- If there is a
  replacement of key technical or management staff during the project,
  sometimes the new people that inherit the project find that they
  don’t like the new system any better than the one it replaces –
  leading them to start potentially a third system.
- Sometimes you might
  succeed partially, and create a new version of a system -but when it
  comes time to go back and re-write lower importance systems to start
  using the new system, people are too busy making cool new things with
  the new system. Now you have two systems. Or, if you’ve already done
  this once before, you’ll have three.

All of these trouble points are
   manageable of course. It can be helpful to re-arrange teams, keep
   clean separation between systems, pay special attention to project
   direction, and set realistic goals around replacing the existing
   system.

Answer (score 4):

The old school name for this is "wrapper".  It sounds great; who wants to mess with the old application when you can write something new and clean to isolate it?  The problem is that it creates a layer of goo, and it isn't long before somebody decides that the wrapper itself is messy.  What's the solution to this? Another wrapper?  As I see it, such wrappers and "stranglers" basically end up armor-plating the original application and eventually make your life harder.  But people often choose short-term solutions that are suboptimal in the long term.  After all, nobody will notice until you're long gone.

Comment: I'm curious about implementing a "wrapper" that's thoroughly unit tested so that it can serve as a façade to the legacy system which should theoretically hide the complexity of the legacy system from the client. That approach is an anti-pattern?

Comment: Unless your wrapper offers *complete* functionality of the underlying wrapped mechanism, it (by definition) cuts off some of the functionality.  If you need that functionality later, the wrapper becomes an obstacle. If you have to support something else, do you build a second wrapper on top of the first?   People claim they are hiding the complexity of the legacy system; what they are actually doing is creating a different version of complexity, usually based on what's convenient for the moment because management won't stand for any extra invested energy.  Thus... armor plating.

Comment: I read your profile. Can you mentor me from time to time?

Comment: Send me email to discuss.  My email address is in my profile.

Comment: (Oh.  Another silver bullet.   Yay.)  This is not the place to have a discussion about a topic different than the question or this answer.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience the driver for doing this is to add additional functionality rather than obsoleting the original code base. Once the new functionality has been added then the immediate business case for completing the change is weakened and momentum is lost. Obviously this doesn't have to happen and you should at the outset plan to avoid this.

Regards